# Google nest router auto setting to bridge mode

Tags: networking

So I live in a shipping container and it’s my Xbox, pc tv etc have all been hard wired but for my phone and Nintendo switch I wanted to use wifi so I brought a google nest router but when I plug it in it won’t connect I went into the google home setting and it’s auto set to bridge mode and I can’t find a way to change that. It seems in bridge mode it doesn’t use the Ethernet cable it just exstends the Wi-Fi and I need help on finding a way to make it use Ethernet
[1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGK4V.jpg

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This dosnt make sence to me 